# Ckeditor force custom style attribute to specific elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to force the inline **style** attributes for all **p** elements. How can I do this?
I've tried to do this:

```
CKEDITOR.config.format_p= { element : 'p', attributes : { style : 'padding:10px;' } }
```

This line is executed and appears in the dom, but nothing really changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[config.format_p](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.format_p) is the style that will be applied when "Paragraph" selected in the [Styles](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles) combobox. If you want to change all p elements just add your own [custom css](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsCss) file into the CKEditor body.

Comment: ok, but is it possible to setup ckeditor to append these styles with the resulting html?

Comment: I am still looking for a way to have inline attributes, not the outside rules.

Comment: So use [Styles](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles). Define in config (inline or in js) your styles `CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('my_styles', [{ name : 'Paragraph with padding', element : 'p', styles : { 'padding' : '10px' } }, ... ]);`. [Default styles](http://svn.ckeditor.com/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/styles/styles/default.js) for the reference. And be sure that `Styles` plugin enabled on your toolbar.

Comment: It turned out that I can only use inline styles for my specific task. [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503401/ckeditor-force-custom-style-attribute-to-specific-elements) how I've solved this with dataprocessor.

Comment: I also need ckeditor to generate inline styles (i'm using it to craft an email). How can I do this ?